# Laravel hasMany with condition based on additional relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

In my issue, I have a shop. A shop has many aisles and each aisle has many items. I have created 3 tables:

`Shop -> id and name`

`Aisles -> id, shop_id, name`

`Aisle_items -> id, aisle_id, name`

I'm trying to retrieve the shop and a list of aisles that have items in a single query.

My shop model has a `hasMany` function of `aisles()`:

```
public function aisles() {
   return $this->hasMany(Aisle::class, 'shop_id', 'id')->orderBy('name', 'ASC');
}
```

and my Aisle model has a `hasMany` function of `items()`:

```
public function items() {
  return $this->hasMany(AisleItem::class)->orderBy('name');
}
```

What do I need to add to the `aisles()` function to retrieve only aisles with items?

Would it be better in the query itself to find this information as opposed to through the model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`has`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) to only retrieve records that actually have a relationship

```
$aisles = $shop->aisles()->has('items')->get()
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's use Laravel's `Has Many Through` relation https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

```php
public function aislesItems()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(AisleItem::class, Aisle::class);
}
```

Comment: He is not asking to retrieve the items from the shop